# Degrees or radians for angle in complex equation

Tags: complex-numbers

If you were asked to convert a complex equation to polar form :

$r\cos(\theta) + ir\sin(\theta)$

Does the angle have to be in radians for the value of theta or can the angle be in degrees too ?

In which form would the angle have to be in radians ?

Comment: It is the same if you accept that for example $60^\circ=\frac\pi3$, that is, ${}^\circ$ denotes the conversion factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the angle can also be in degrees.

To find $\theta$ from the Cartesian representation, you can form a right triangle with the opposite side as the $y$-coordinate, and the adjacent side as the $x$-coordinate.

Then we use the formula $\theta = \tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x}$, and this value can be expressed either in degrees or radians. This is since $x,y$ are dimensionless, so $\tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x}$ also has to be dimensionless.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, when you are doing calculus, only use radians, otherwise derivatives require an annoying conversion factor.

(In the case at hand, it doesn't make a difference, but it is unnatural to use degrees.)

Comment: A personal remark: degrees exist for historical reasons (like grades) and are somewhat arbitrary/inconvenient (not counting the degree/minutes/seconds are a nightmare). Radians are the best choice for calculus. But we are missing a truly practical unit: turns.

Answer (score 2):

The magnitude of the complex number is given only by $r$ and $\theta$ is only its argument, which represents the angle by which it is inclined to the real axis in the Argand plane.
So you may use $\theta$ either in degrees or in radians, because we're just finding $\sin$ and $\cos$ of that angle.